# How to Airplay from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: audio

Is it possible for a RPi to stream AirPlay **to** another RPi?

I have some RPi's connected to various speakers in different rooms. I easily can stream from my phone (or computer, or tablet) to any of them.

However I also have an old turntable in one of those rooms that I'd like to modify so it could stream from it to my other pi's. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I haven't tried this yet -- Maybe I will at a later point. But you can set up pulseaudio to stream to [AirPlay sinks](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index8h2). The modules in question are module-raop-sink and module-raop-discover.